# How can a label have a precision of 100% and specifity of 100% as well?

Tags: machine-learning

I am using the Java library [Mulan](http://mulan.sourceforge.net/) to do [Multi-Label classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification).

My feature vector consists of 144 labels named "Slot1" to "Slot144".
Each label can have the values 1 or 0. I know for a fact that labels between "Slot1" and "Slot27" are always 0 and always get classified as such (true negatives).

```
--------------------------------------------
SLOT1 | SLOT2 | SLOT3 | SLOT4 | .. | SLOT27
--------------------------------------------
  0   |   0   |   0   |   0   | .. |   0
--------------------------------------------
```

Mulan can evaluate predictive models with 10-fold cross validation. Here are the results of an evaluation using Support Vector Machine:

```
Hamming Loss: 0,0608±0,0287
Subset Accuracy: 0,4708±0,1851
Example-Based Precision: 0,8026±0,1142
Example-Based Recall: 0,7973±0,1145
Example-Based F Measure: 0,7948±0,1132
Example-Based Accuracy: 0,7628±0,1160
Example-Based Specificity: 0,9712±0,0241
Micro-averaged Precision: 0,7375±0,2251
Micro-averaged Recall: 0,7066±0,1725
Micro-averaged F-Measure: 0,6979±0,1597
Micro-averaged Specificity: 0,9703±0,0264
Macro-averaged Precision: 0,8694±0,0649
Slot1: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot2: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot3: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot4: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot5: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot6: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot7: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot8: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot9: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot10: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot11: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot12: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot13: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot14: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot15: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot16: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot17: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot18: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot19: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot20: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot21: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot22: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot23: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot24: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot25: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot26: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot27: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot28: 0,8000±0,2560 Slot29: 0,8000±0,2560 Slot30: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot31: 0,3000±0,2610 Slot32: 0,1500±0,1302 Slot33: 0,5700±0,0952 Slot34: 0,5833±0,0576 Slot35: 0,7417±0,1003 Slot36: 0,7583±0,0995 Slot37: 0,7750±0,1036 Slot38: 0,7917±0,0960 Slot39: 0,7917±0,0960 Slot40: 0,7917±0,0960 Slot41: 0,8167±0,0980 Slot42: 0,8167±0,0980 Slot43: 0,8167±0,0980 Slot44: 0,8167±0,0980 Slot45: 0,8167±0,0980 Slot46: 0,8000±0,1066 Slot47: 0,8000±0,1066 Slot48: 0,8000±0,1066 Slot49: 0,7833±0,1200 Slot50: 0,8000±0,0954 Slot51: 0,8000±0,0954 Slot52: 0,7833±0,1034 Slot53: 0,8000±0,0954 Slot54: 0,7833±0,1034 Slot55: 0,7833±0,1034 Slot56: 0,7833±0,1034 Slot57: 0,7833±0,1034 Slot58: 0,7667±0,0940 Slot59: 0,7500±0,1007 Slot60: 0,7333±0,1123 Slot61: 0,7500±0,1007 Slot62: 0,7667±0,0940 Slot63: 0,7167±0,0489 Slot64: 0,6917±0,0439 Slot65: 0,6517±0,0421 Slot66: 0,6567±0,0451 Slot67: 0,4267±0,0809 Slot68: 0,2333±0,0568 Slot69: 0,3167±0,1725 Slot70: 0,1000±0,1090 Slot71: 0,2000±0,1960 Slot72: 0,2000±0,1960 Slot73: 0,3000±0,2610 Slot74: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot75: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot76: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot77: 0,6000±0,3240 Slot78: 0,6000±0,3240 Slot79: 0,7000±0,3010 Slot80: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot81: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot82: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot83: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot84: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot85: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot86: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot87: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot88: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot89: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot90: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot91: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot92: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot93: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot94: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot95: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot96: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot97: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot98: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot99: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot100: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot101: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot102: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot103: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot104: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot105: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot106: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot107: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot108: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot109: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot110: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot111: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot112: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot113: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot114: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot115: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot116: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot117: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot118: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot119: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot120: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot121: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot122: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot123: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot124: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot125: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot126: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot127: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot128: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot129: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot130: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot131: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot132: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot133: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot134: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot135: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot136: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot137: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot138: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot139: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot140: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot141: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot142: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot143: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot144: 1,0000±0,1000 
Macro-averaged Recall: 0,8756±0,0572
Slot1: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot2: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot3: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot4: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot5: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot6: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot7: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot8: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot9: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot10: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot11: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot12: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot13: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot14: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot15: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot16: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot17: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot18: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot19: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot20: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot21: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot22: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot23: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot24: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot25: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot26: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot27: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot28: 0,8000±0,2560 Slot29: 0,8000±0,2560 Slot30: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot31: 0,3000±0,2610 Slot32: 0,1500±0,1302 Slot33: 0,5083±0,0887 Slot34: 0,7083±0,0432 Slot35: 0,8100±0,1388 Slot36: 0,8100±0,1388 Slot37: 0,8124±0,1279 Slot38: 0,8124±0,1279 Slot39: 0,8124±0,1279 Slot40: 0,8124±0,1279 Slot41: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot42: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot43: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot44: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot45: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot46: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot47: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot48: 0,8190±0,1257 Slot49: 0,8024±0,1327 Slot50: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot51: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot52: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot53: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot54: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot55: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot56: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot57: 0,8000±0,1324 Slot58: 0,7917±0,1335 Slot59: 0,7917±0,1335 Slot60: 0,7917±0,1335 Slot61: 0,7917±0,1335 Slot62: 0,8083±0,1270 Slot63: 0,7083±0,0321 Slot64: 0,7017±0,0340 Slot65: 0,6317±0,0423 Slot66: 0,6333±0,0657 Slot67: 0,5000±0,0861 Slot68: 0,3333±0,1167 Slot69: 0,4167±0,2618 Slot70: 0,1000±0,1090 Slot71: 0,2000±0,1960 Slot72: 0,2000±0,1960 Slot73: 0,3000±0,2610 Slot74: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot75: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot76: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot77: 0,6000±0,3240 Slot78: 0,6000±0,3240 Slot79: 0,7000±0,3010 Slot80: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot81: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot82: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot83: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot84: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot85: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot86: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot87: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot88: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot89: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot90: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot91: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot92: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot93: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot94: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot95: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot96: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot97: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot98: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot99: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot100: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot101: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot102: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot103: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot104: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot105: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot106: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot107: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot108: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot109: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot110: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot111: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot112: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot113: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot114: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot115: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot116: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot117: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot118: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot119: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot120: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot121: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot122: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot123: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot124: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot125: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot126: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot127: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot128: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot129: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot130: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot131: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot132: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot133: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot134: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot135: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot136: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot137: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot138: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot139: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot140: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot141: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot142: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot143: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot144: 1,0000±0,1000 
Macro-averaged F-Measure: 0,8663±0,0541
Slot1: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot2: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot3: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot4: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot5: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot6: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot7: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot8: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot9: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot10: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot11: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot12: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot13: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot14: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot15: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot16: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot17: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot18: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot19: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot20: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot21: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot22: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot23: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot24: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot25: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot26: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot27: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot28: 0,8000±0,2560 Slot29: 0,8000±0,2560 Slot30: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot31: 0,3000±0,2610 Slot32: 0,1500±0,1302 Slot33: 0,5050±0,0661 Slot34: 0,6088±0,0342 Slot35: 0,7486±0,0986 Slot36: 0,7595±0,1006 Slot37: 0,7704±0,0980 Slot38: 0,7837±0,0965 Slot39: 0,7837±0,0965 Slot40: 0,7837±0,0965 Slot41: 0,7971±0,0947 Slot42: 0,7971±0,0947 Slot43: 0,7971±0,0947 Slot44: 0,7971±0,0947 Slot45: 0,7971±0,0947 Slot46: 0,7837±0,0965 Slot47: 0,7837±0,0965 Slot48: 0,7837±0,0965 Slot49: 0,7575±0,1062 Slot50: 0,7786±0,0967 Slot51: 0,7786±0,0967 Slot52: 0,7652±0,0980 Slot53: 0,7786±0,0967 Slot54: 0,7652±0,0980 Slot55: 0,7652±0,0980 Slot56: 0,7652±0,0980 Slot57: 0,7652±0,0980 Slot58: 0,7595±0,0974 Slot59: 0,7462±0,0981 Slot60: 0,7295±0,1035 Slot61: 0,7462±0,0981 Slot62: 0,7690±0,0944 Slot63: 0,7024±0,0331 Slot64: 0,6890±0,0340 Slot65: 0,6279±0,0316 Slot66: 0,6017±0,0360 Slot67: 0,4109±0,0505 Slot68: 0,2638±0,0665 Slot69: 0,3500±0,1936 Slot70: 0,1000±0,1090 Slot71: 0,2000±0,1960 Slot72: 0,2000±0,1960 Slot73: 0,3000±0,2610 Slot74: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot75: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot76: 0,5000±0,3250 Slot77: 0,6000±0,3240 Slot78: 0,6000±0,3240 Slot79: 0,7000±0,3010 Slot80: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot81: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot82: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot83: 0,9000±0,1890 Slot84: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot85: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot86: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot87: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot88: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot89: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot90: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot91: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot92: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot93: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot94: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot95: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot96: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot97: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot98: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot99: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot100: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot101: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot102: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot103: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot104: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot105: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot106: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot107: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot108: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot109: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot110: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot111: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot112: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot113: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot114: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot115: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot116: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot117: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot118: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot119: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot120: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot121: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot122: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot123: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot124: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot125: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot126: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot127: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot128: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot129: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot130: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot131: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot132: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot133: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot134: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot135: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot136: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot137: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot138: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot139: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot140: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot141: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot142: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot143: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot144: 1,0000±0,1000 
Macro-averaged Specificity: 0,9571±0,0395
Slot1: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot2: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot3: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot4: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot5: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot6: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot7: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot8: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot9: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot10: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot11: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot12: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot13: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot14: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot15: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot16: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot17: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot18: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot19: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot20: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot21: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot22: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot23: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot24: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot25: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot26: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot27: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot28: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot29: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot30: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot31: 0,9857±0,1018 Slot32: 0,9117±0,1083 Slot33: 0,8259±0,1263 Slot34: 0,7530±0,1229 Slot35: 0,8039±0,1295 Slot36: 0,8206±0,1221 Slot37: 0,8573±0,1218 Slot38: 0,8673±0,1136 Slot39: 0,8673±0,1136 Slot40: 0,8673±0,1136 Slot41: 0,8923±0,1134 Slot42: 0,8923±0,1134 Slot43: 0,8923±0,1134 Slot44: 0,8923±0,1134 Slot45: 0,8923±0,1134 Slot46: 0,8823±0,1221 Slot47: 0,8823±0,1221 Slot48: 0,8823±0,1221 Slot49: 0,8723±0,1294 Slot50: 0,8389±0,1252 Slot51: 0,8389±0,1252 Slot52: 0,8289±0,1327 Slot53: 0,8389±0,1252 Slot54: 0,8289±0,1327 Slot55: 0,8289±0,1327 Slot56: 0,8289±0,1327 Slot57: 0,8289±0,1327 Slot58: 0,8223±0,1221 Slot59: 0,8123±0,1294 Slot60: 0,8056±0,1352 Slot61: 0,8123±0,1294 Slot62: 0,8256±0,1221 Slot63: 0,8159±0,1124 Slot64: 0,7909±0,1089 Slot65: 0,7875±0,0976 Slot66: 0,8417±0,1070 Slot67: 0,7040±0,1045 Slot68: 0,8166±0,0909 Slot69: 0,8696±0,1091 Slot70: 0,9653±0,1052 Slot71: 0,9778±0,1044 Slot72: 0,9778±0,1044 Slot73: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot74: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot75: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot76: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot77: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot78: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot79: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot80: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot81: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot82: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot83: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot84: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot85: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot86: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot87: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot88: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot89: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot90: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot91: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot92: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot93: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot94: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot95: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot96: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot97: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot98: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot99: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot100: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot101: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot102: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot103: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot104: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot105: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot106: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot107: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot108: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot109: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot110: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot111: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot112: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot113: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot114: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot115: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot116: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot117: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot118: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot119: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot120: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot121: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot122: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot123: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot124: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot125: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot126: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot127: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot128: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot129: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot130: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot131: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot132: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot133: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot134: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot135: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot136: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot137: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot138: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot139: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot140: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot141: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot142: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot143: 1,0000±0,1000 Slot144: 1,0000±0,1000 
Average Precision: 0,6994±0,1140
Coverage: 42,6333±21,0269
OneError: 0,7667±0,1823
IsError: 0,4597±0,2051
ErrorSetSize: 352,1556±218,8207
Ranking Loss: 0,0925±0,0618
Mean Average Precision: 0,7546±0,1668
Slot1: NaN±NaN Slot2: NaN±NaN Slot3: NaN±NaN Slot4: NaN±NaN Slot5: NaN±NaN Slot6: NaN±NaN Slot7: NaN±NaN Slot8: NaN±NaN Slot9: NaN±NaN Slot10: NaN±NaN Slot11: NaN±NaN Slot12: NaN±NaN Slot13: NaN±NaN Slot14: NaN±NaN Slot15: NaN±NaN Slot16: NaN±NaN Slot17: NaN±NaN Slot18: NaN±NaN Slot19: NaN±NaN Slot20: NaN±NaN Slot21: NaN±NaN Slot22: NaN±NaN Slot23: NaN±NaN Slot24: NaN±NaN Slot25: NaN±NaN Slot26: NaN±NaN Slot27: NaN±NaN Slot28: NaN±NaN Slot29: NaN±NaN Slot30: NaN±NaN Slot31: NaN±NaN Slot32: NaN±NaN Slot33: NaN±NaN Slot34: 0,6525±0,0701 Slot35: 0,8032±0,0862 Slot36: 0,8628±0,1370 Slot37: 0,8623±0,1375 Slot38: 0,8560±0,1370 Slot39: 0,8560±0,1370 Slot40: 0,8560±0,1370 Slot41: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot42: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot43: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot44: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot45: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot46: 0,8827±0,1319 Slot47: 0,8827±0,1319 Slot48: 0,8827±0,1319 Slot49: 0,9015±0,1328 Slot50: 0,8817±0,1307 Slot51: 0,8817±0,1307 Slot52: 0,8297±0,0832 Slot53: 0,8817±0,1307 Slot54: 0,8297±0,0818 Slot55: 0,8797±0,1308 Slot56: 0,8797±0,1308 Slot57: 0,8797±0,1308 Slot58: 0,8456±0,1329 Slot59: 0,7769±0,0856 Slot60: 0,8269±0,1351 Slot61: 0,7936±0,0835 Slot62: 0,8436±0,1329 Slot63: NaN±NaN Slot64: NaN±NaN Slot65: NaN±NaN Slot66: NaN±NaN Slot67: NaN±NaN Slot68: NaN±NaN Slot69: NaN±NaN Slot70: NaN±NaN Slot71: NaN±NaN Slot72: NaN±NaN Slot73: NaN±NaN Slot74: NaN±NaN Slot75: NaN±NaN Slot76: NaN±NaN Slot77: NaN±NaN Slot78: NaN±NaN Slot79: NaN±NaN Slot80: NaN±NaN Slot81: NaN±NaN Slot82: NaN±NaN Slot83: NaN±NaN Slot84: NaN±NaN Slot85: NaN±NaN Slot86: NaN±NaN Slot87: NaN±NaN Slot88: NaN±NaN Slot89: NaN±NaN Slot90: NaN±NaN Slot91: NaN±NaN Slot92: NaN±NaN Slot93: NaN±NaN Slot94: NaN±NaN Slot95: NaN±NaN Slot96: NaN±NaN Slot97: NaN±NaN Slot98: NaN±NaN Slot99: NaN±NaN Slot100: NaN±NaN Slot101: NaN±NaN Slot102: NaN±NaN Slot103: NaN±NaN Slot104: NaN±NaN Slot105: NaN±NaN Slot106: NaN±NaN Slot107: NaN±NaN Slot108: NaN±NaN Slot109: NaN±NaN Slot110: NaN±NaN Slot111: NaN±NaN Slot112: NaN±NaN Slot113: NaN±NaN Slot114: NaN±NaN Slot115: NaN±NaN Slot116: NaN±NaN Slot117: NaN±NaN Slot118: NaN±NaN Slot119: NaN±NaN Slot120: NaN±NaN Slot121: NaN±NaN Slot122: NaN±NaN Slot123: NaN±NaN Slot124: NaN±NaN Slot125: NaN±NaN Slot126: NaN±NaN Slot127: NaN±NaN Slot128: NaN±NaN Slot129: NaN±NaN Slot130: NaN±NaN Slot131: NaN±NaN Slot132: NaN±NaN Slot133: NaN±NaN Slot134: NaN±NaN Slot135: NaN±NaN Slot136: NaN±NaN Slot137: NaN±NaN Slot138: NaN±NaN Slot139: NaN±NaN Slot140: NaN±NaN Slot141: NaN±NaN Slot142: NaN±NaN Slot143: NaN±NaN Slot144: NaN±NaN 
Geometric Mean Average Precision: NaN±NaN
Slot1: NaN±NaN Slot2: NaN±NaN Slot3: NaN±NaN Slot4: NaN±NaN Slot5: NaN±NaN Slot6: NaN±NaN Slot7: NaN±NaN Slot8: NaN±NaN Slot9: NaN±NaN Slot10: NaN±NaN Slot11: NaN±NaN Slot12: NaN±NaN Slot13: NaN±NaN Slot14: NaN±NaN Slot15: NaN±NaN Slot16: NaN±NaN Slot17: NaN±NaN Slot18: NaN±NaN Slot19: NaN±NaN Slot20: NaN±NaN Slot21: NaN±NaN Slot22: NaN±NaN Slot23: NaN±NaN Slot24: NaN±NaN Slot25: NaN±NaN Slot26: NaN±NaN Slot27: NaN±NaN Slot28: NaN±NaN Slot29: NaN±NaN Slot30: NaN±NaN Slot31: NaN±NaN Slot32: NaN±NaN Slot33: NaN±NaN Slot34: 0,6525±0,0701 Slot35: 0,8032±0,0862 Slot36: 0,8628±0,1370 Slot37: 0,8623±0,1375 Slot38: 0,8560±0,1370 Slot39: 0,8560±0,1370 Slot40: 0,8560±0,1370 Slot41: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot42: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot43: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot44: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot45: 0,8848±0,1317 Slot46: 0,8827±0,1319 Slot47: 0,8827±0,1319 Slot48: 0,8827±0,1319 Slot49: 0,9015±0,1328 Slot50: 0,8817±0,1307 Slot51: 0,8817±0,1307 Slot52: 0,8297±0,0832 Slot53: 0,8817±0,1307 Slot54: 0,8297±0,0818 Slot55: 0,8797±0,1308 Slot56: 0,8797±0,1308 Slot57: 0,8797±0,1308 Slot58: 0,8456±0,1329 Slot59: 0,7769±0,0856 Slot60: 0,8269±0,1351 Slot61: 0,7936±0,0835 Slot62: 0,8436±0,1329 Slot63: NaN±NaN Slot64: NaN±NaN Slot65: NaN±NaN Slot66: NaN±NaN Slot67: NaN±NaN Slot68: NaN±NaN Slot69: NaN±NaN Slot70: NaN±NaN Slot71: NaN±NaN Slot72: NaN±NaN Slot73: NaN±NaN Slot74: NaN±NaN Slot75: NaN±NaN Slot76: NaN±NaN Slot77: NaN±NaN Slot78: NaN±NaN Slot79: NaN±NaN Slot80: NaN±NaN Slot81: NaN±NaN Slot82: NaN±NaN Slot83: NaN±NaN Slot84: NaN±NaN Slot85: NaN±NaN Slot86: NaN±NaN Slot87: NaN±NaN Slot88: NaN±NaN Slot89: NaN±NaN Slot90: NaN±NaN Slot91: NaN±NaN Slot92: NaN±NaN Slot93: NaN±NaN Slot94: NaN±NaN Slot95: NaN±NaN Slot96: NaN±NaN Slot97: NaN±NaN Slot98: NaN±NaN Slot99: NaN±NaN Slot100: NaN±NaN Slot101: NaN±NaN Slot102: NaN±NaN Slot103: NaN±NaN Slot104: NaN±NaN Slot105: NaN±NaN Slot106: NaN±NaN Slot107: NaN±NaN Slot108: NaN±NaN Slot109: NaN±NaN Slot110: NaN±NaN Slot111: NaN±NaN Slot112: NaN±NaN Slot113: NaN±NaN Slot114: NaN±NaN Slot115: NaN±NaN Slot116: NaN±NaN Slot117: NaN±NaN Slot118: NaN±NaN Slot119: NaN±NaN Slot120: NaN±NaN Slot121: NaN±NaN Slot122: NaN±NaN Slot123: NaN±NaN Slot124: NaN±NaN Slot125: NaN±NaN Slot126: NaN±NaN Slot127: NaN±NaN Slot128: NaN±NaN Slot129: NaN±NaN Slot130: NaN±NaN Slot131: NaN±NaN Slot132: NaN±NaN Slot133: NaN±NaN Slot134: NaN±NaN Slot135: NaN±NaN Slot136: NaN±NaN Slot137: NaN±NaN Slot138: NaN±NaN Slot139: NaN±NaN Slot140: NaN±NaN Slot141: NaN±NaN Slot142: NaN±NaN Slot143: NaN±NaN Slot144: NaN±NaN 
Mean Average Interpolated Precision: 0,7619±0,1653
Slot1: NaN±NaN Slot2: NaN±NaN Slot3: NaN±NaN Slot4: NaN±NaN Slot5: NaN±NaN Slot6: NaN±NaN Slot7: NaN±NaN Slot8: NaN±NaN Slot9: NaN±NaN Slot10: NaN±NaN Slot11: NaN±NaN Slot12: NaN±NaN Slot13: NaN±NaN Slot14: NaN±NaN Slot15: NaN±NaN Slot16: NaN±NaN Slot17: NaN±NaN Slot18: NaN±NaN Slot19: NaN±NaN Slot20: NaN±NaN Slot21: NaN±NaN Slot22: NaN±NaN Slot23: NaN±NaN Slot24: NaN±NaN Slot25: NaN±NaN Slot26: NaN±NaN Slot27: NaN±NaN Slot28: NaN±NaN Slot29: NaN±NaN Slot30: NaN±NaN Slot31: NaN±NaN Slot32: NaN±NaN Slot33: NaN±NaN Slot34: 0,6758±0,0699 Slot35: 0,8096±0,0847 Slot36: 0,8688±0,1340 Slot37: 0,8704±0,1341 Slot38: 0,8629±0,1336 Slot39: 0,8629±0,1336 Slot40: 0,8629±0,1336 Slot41: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot42: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot43: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot44: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot45: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot46: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot47: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot48: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot49: 0,8996±0,1328 Slot50: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot51: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot52: 0,8330±0,0829 Slot53: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot54: 0,8305±0,0818 Slot55: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot56: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot57: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot58: 0,8555±0,1298 Slot59: 0,7905±0,0822 Slot60: 0,8371±0,1324 Slot61: 0,8055±0,0806 Slot62: 0,8562±0,1298 Slot63: NaN±NaN Slot64: NaN±NaN Slot65: NaN±NaN Slot66: NaN±NaN Slot67: NaN±NaN Slot68: NaN±NaN Slot69: NaN±NaN Slot70: NaN±NaN Slot71: NaN±NaN Slot72: NaN±NaN Slot73: NaN±NaN Slot74: NaN±NaN Slot75: NaN±NaN Slot76: NaN±NaN Slot77: NaN±NaN Slot78: NaN±NaN Slot79: NaN±NaN Slot80: NaN±NaN Slot81: NaN±NaN Slot82: NaN±NaN Slot83: NaN±NaN Slot84: NaN±NaN Slot85: NaN±NaN Slot86: NaN±NaN Slot87: NaN±NaN Slot88: NaN±NaN Slot89: NaN±NaN Slot90: NaN±NaN Slot91: NaN±NaN Slot92: NaN±NaN Slot93: NaN±NaN Slot94: NaN±NaN Slot95: NaN±NaN Slot96: NaN±NaN Slot97: NaN±NaN Slot98: NaN±NaN Slot99: NaN±NaN Slot100: NaN±NaN Slot101: NaN±NaN Slot102: NaN±NaN Slot103: NaN±NaN Slot104: NaN±NaN Slot105: NaN±NaN Slot106: NaN±NaN Slot107: NaN±NaN Slot108: NaN±NaN Slot109: NaN±NaN Slot110: NaN±NaN Slot111: NaN±NaN Slot112: NaN±NaN Slot113: NaN±NaN Slot114: NaN±NaN Slot115: NaN±NaN Slot116: NaN±NaN Slot117: NaN±NaN Slot118: NaN±NaN Slot119: NaN±NaN Slot120: NaN±NaN Slot121: NaN±NaN Slot122: NaN±NaN Slot123: NaN±NaN Slot124: NaN±NaN Slot125: NaN±NaN Slot126: NaN±NaN Slot127: NaN±NaN Slot128: NaN±NaN Slot129: NaN±NaN Slot130: NaN±NaN Slot131: NaN±NaN Slot132: NaN±NaN Slot133: NaN±NaN Slot134: NaN±NaN Slot135: NaN±NaN Slot136: NaN±NaN Slot137: NaN±NaN Slot138: NaN±NaN Slot139: NaN±NaN Slot140: NaN±NaN Slot141: NaN±NaN Slot142: NaN±NaN Slot143: NaN±NaN Slot144: NaN±NaN 
Geometric Mean Average Interpolated Precision: NaN±NaN
Slot1: NaN±NaN Slot2: NaN±NaN Slot3: NaN±NaN Slot4: NaN±NaN Slot5: NaN±NaN Slot6: NaN±NaN Slot7: NaN±NaN Slot8: NaN±NaN Slot9: NaN±NaN Slot10: NaN±NaN Slot11: NaN±NaN Slot12: NaN±NaN Slot13: NaN±NaN Slot14: NaN±NaN Slot15: NaN±NaN Slot16: NaN±NaN Slot17: NaN±NaN Slot18: NaN±NaN Slot19: NaN±NaN Slot20: NaN±NaN Slot21: NaN±NaN Slot22: NaN±NaN Slot23: NaN±NaN Slot24: NaN±NaN Slot25: NaN±NaN Slot26: NaN±NaN Slot27: NaN±NaN Slot28: NaN±NaN Slot29: NaN±NaN Slot30: NaN±NaN Slot31: NaN±NaN Slot32: NaN±NaN Slot33: NaN±NaN Slot34: 0,6758±0,0699 Slot35: 0,8096±0,0847 Slot36: 0,8688±0,1340 Slot37: 0,8704±0,1341 Slot38: 0,8629±0,1336 Slot39: 0,8629±0,1336 Slot40: 0,8629±0,1336 Slot41: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot42: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot43: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot44: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot45: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot46: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot47: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot48: 0,8854±0,1314 Slot49: 0,8996±0,1328 Slot50: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot51: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot52: 0,8330±0,0829 Slot53: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot54: 0,8305±0,0818 Slot55: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot56: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot57: 0,8805±0,1308 Slot58: 0,8555±0,1298 Slot59: 0,7905±0,0822 Slot60: 0,8371±0,1324 Slot61: 0,8055±0,0806 Slot62: 0,8562±0,1298 Slot63: NaN±NaN Slot64: NaN±NaN Slot65: NaN±NaN Slot66: NaN±NaN Slot67: NaN±NaN Slot68: NaN±NaN Slot69: NaN±NaN Slot70: NaN±NaN Slot71: NaN±NaN Slot72: NaN±NaN Slot73: NaN±NaN Slot74: NaN±NaN Slot75: NaN±NaN Slot76: NaN±NaN Slot77: NaN±NaN Slot78: NaN±NaN Slot79: NaN±NaN Slot80: NaN±NaN Slot81: NaN±NaN Slot82: NaN±NaN Slot83: NaN±NaN Slot84: NaN±NaN Slot85: NaN±NaN Slot86: NaN±NaN Slot87: NaN±NaN Slot88: NaN±NaN Slot89: NaN±NaN Slot90: NaN±NaN Slot91: NaN±NaN Slot92: NaN±NaN Slot93: NaN±NaN Slot94: NaN±NaN Slot95: NaN±NaN Slot96: NaN±NaN Slot97: NaN±NaN Slot98: NaN±NaN Slot99: NaN±NaN Slot100: NaN±NaN Slot101: NaN±NaN Slot102: NaN±NaN Slot103: NaN±NaN Slot104: NaN±NaN Slot105: NaN±NaN Slot106: NaN±NaN Slot107: NaN±NaN Slot108: NaN±NaN Slot109: NaN±NaN Slot110: NaN±NaN Slot111: NaN±NaN Slot112: NaN±NaN Slot113: NaN±NaN Slot114: NaN±NaN Slot115: NaN±NaN Slot116: NaN±NaN Slot117: NaN±NaN Slot118: NaN±NaN Slot119: NaN±NaN Slot120: NaN±NaN Slot121: NaN±NaN Slot122: NaN±NaN Slot123: NaN±NaN Slot124: NaN±NaN Slot125: NaN±NaN Slot126: NaN±NaN Slot127: NaN±NaN Slot128: NaN±NaN Slot129: NaN±NaN Slot130: NaN±NaN Slot131: NaN±NaN Slot132: NaN±NaN Slot133: NaN±NaN Slot134: NaN±NaN Slot135: NaN±NaN Slot136: NaN±NaN Slot137: NaN±NaN Slot138: NaN±NaN Slot139: NaN±NaN Slot140: NaN±NaN Slot141: NaN±NaN Slot142: NaN±NaN Slot143: NaN±NaN Slot144: NaN±NaN 
Micro-averaged AUC: 0,8462±0,0883
Macro-averaged AUC: NaN±NaN
Slot1: NaN±NaN Slot2: NaN±NaN Slot3: NaN±NaN Slot4: NaN±NaN Slot5: NaN±NaN Slot6: NaN±NaN Slot7: NaN±NaN Slot8: NaN±NaN Slot9: NaN±NaN Slot10: NaN±NaN Slot11: NaN±NaN Slot12: NaN±NaN Slot13: NaN±NaN Slot14: NaN±NaN Slot15: NaN±NaN Slot16: NaN±NaN Slot17: NaN±NaN Slot18: NaN±NaN Slot19: NaN±NaN Slot20: NaN±NaN Slot21: NaN±NaN Slot22: NaN±NaN Slot23: NaN±NaN Slot24: NaN±NaN Slot25: NaN±NaN Slot26: NaN±NaN Slot27: NaN±NaN Slot28: NaN±NaN Slot29: NaN±NaN Slot30: NaN±NaN Slot31: NaN±NaN Slot32: NaN±NaN Slot33: NaN±NaN Slot34: 0,7307±0,0590 Slot35: 0,8080±0,1045 Slot36: 0,8153±0,1117 Slot37: 0,8348±0,1107 Slot38: 0,8398±0,1097 Slot39: 0,8398±0,1097 Slot40: 0,8398±0,1097 Slot41: 0,8557±0,1070 Slot42: 0,8557±0,1070 Slot43: 0,8557±0,1070 Slot44: 0,8557±0,1070 Slot45: 0,8557±0,1070 Slot46: 0,8507±0,1082 Slot47: 0,8507±0,1082 Slot48: 0,8507±0,1082 Slot49: 0,8373±0,1119 Slot50: 0,8195±0,1111 Slot51: 0,8195±0,1111 Slot52: 0,8015±0,1076 Slot53: 0,8195±0,1111 Slot54: 0,8082±0,1055 Slot55: 0,8145±0,1119 Slot56: 0,8145±0,1119 Slot57: 0,8145±0,1119 Slot58: 0,8070±0,1108 Slot59: 0,7957±0,1051 Slot60: 0,7986±0,1122 Slot61: 0,7957±0,1051 Slot62: 0,8170±0,1088 Slot63: NaN±NaN Slot64: NaN±NaN Slot65: NaN±NaN Slot66: NaN±NaN Slot67: NaN±NaN Slot68: NaN±NaN Slot69: NaN±NaN Slot70: NaN±NaN Slot71: NaN±NaN Slot72: NaN±NaN Slot73: NaN±NaN Slot74: NaN±NaN Slot75: NaN±NaN Slot76: NaN±NaN Slot77: NaN±NaN Slot78: NaN±NaN Slot79: NaN±NaN Slot80: NaN±NaN Slot81: NaN±NaN Slot82: NaN±NaN Slot83: NaN±NaN Slot84: NaN±NaN Slot85: NaN±NaN Slot86: NaN±NaN Slot87: NaN±NaN Slot88: NaN±NaN Slot89: NaN±NaN Slot90: NaN±NaN Slot91: NaN±NaN Slot92: NaN±NaN Slot93: NaN±NaN Slot94: NaN±NaN Slot95: NaN±NaN Slot96: NaN±NaN Slot97: NaN±NaN Slot98: NaN±NaN Slot99: NaN±NaN Slot100: NaN±NaN Slot101: NaN±NaN Slot102: NaN±NaN Slot103: NaN±NaN Slot104: NaN±NaN Slot105: NaN±NaN Slot106: NaN±NaN Slot107: NaN±NaN Slot108: NaN±NaN Slot109: NaN±NaN Slot110: NaN±NaN Slot111: NaN±NaN Slot112: NaN±NaN Slot113: NaN±NaN Slot114: NaN±NaN Slot115: NaN±NaN Slot116: NaN±NaN Slot117: NaN±NaN Slot118: NaN±NaN Slot119: NaN±NaN Slot120: NaN±NaN Slot121: NaN±NaN Slot122: NaN±NaN Slot123: NaN±NaN Slot124: NaN±NaN Slot125: NaN±NaN Slot126: NaN±NaN Slot127: NaN±NaN Slot128: NaN±NaN Slot129: NaN±NaN Slot130: NaN±NaN Slot131: NaN±NaN Slot132: NaN±NaN Slot133: NaN±NaN Slot134: NaN±NaN Slot135: NaN±NaN Slot136: NaN±NaN Slot137: NaN±NaN Slot138: NaN±NaN Slot139: NaN±NaN Slot140: NaN±NaN Slot141: NaN±NaN Slot142: NaN±NaN Slot143: NaN±NaN Slot144: NaN±NaN 
Logarithmic Loss: 148,3760±74,9998
```

I ran the cross-fold validation on 5 different algortihms (using the same dataset) and plotted the precision in a graph, to get a better overview:

[image]

[Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) is calculated as:

```
true positives / (true positives + false positives)
```

How can a label that is always 0, and always gets predicted as being 0, have a precision of 100%, when the calculation of precision doesnt include true negatives?

Answer (score 1):

It just occoured to me that I could check the Mulan source code. I believe this answers my own question:

Class: InformationRetrivalMeasures:

```
 /**
     * Computation of precision based on tp, fp and fn. We treat special cases
     * with empty set predictions or/and ground truth as follows: (i) if the
     * algorithm outputs the empty set and the ground truth is the empty set,
     * then we consider precision equal to 1 (ii) if the algorithm outputs the
     * empty set and the ground truth is not empty, then we consider precision
     * equal to 0.
     *
     * @param tp true positives
     * @param fp false positives
     * @param fn false negatives
     * @return the value of precision
     */
    public static double precision(double tp, double fp, double fn) {
        if (tp + fp + fn == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (tp + fp == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return tp / (tp + fp);
    }
```